# AngularJs loads only partial(dashboard.html) on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, .htaccess

i have angualrJs app in which i have enabled HTML5 mode true and also applied required setting on server side .htaccess file like following

**.htaccess file**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /timeLeap/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

also i have inserted `<base href="/dir/">` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

now when i try to refresh page on any state it loads only that state's template only and also angular doesn't get applied

*URL* : `http://localhost/app/data1`

*Response* : state load normal data1.html file only with no angular effect

**Note:**
but if i modify url and do like this it loads data1 state as expected

*URL* : `http://localhost/app/#data1`

*Response* : works as expected

so if anybody has idea then let me know.